# Refactor casting on SQL queries from '::' to CAST on whole codebase

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I use the `field::type` approach to cast fields, but now I have to change it to `CAST(field as type)` on our whole codebase (more than 300 files and 3k lines of code containing  this)

As an example:
`actual_ts::VARCHAR` should be `CAST(actual_ts as VARCHAR)`

It would be easy to write some code to change it if the fields where easily identifiable like just one word without spaces, but we have some stuff like:

```
CASE foo
        WHEN 1 THEN 'a'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'b'
        ELSE NULL
END::VARCHAR(191)
```

or

```
DATEDIFF('ms',lag(some_ts) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY id, other_ts 
        ORDER BY ts), other ts)::FLOAT
```

My issue is to indentify where the field name starts/ends

Comment: Which dbms are you actually using? (The above code snippets will not work on all of the tagged dbms products.)

Comment: On this queries, just Postgres/redshift, but we intend to not depend just on one vendor, thats why we are going to change this

Comment: Watch out for date/time functionality, too often product specific. Try to write ANSI SQL compliant code, when possible.

Comment: You are totally right, we might need to change several functions too

Comment: Trying to do this with a regex across a whole codebase is going to be very dangerous IMO. The simple fact that SQS (at least any of the implementations that I have used) doesn't enforce anything in the way of newlines, spaces, etc.

Comment: you can try different IDEs that beautify the code and find a format that sets one line per output column, then process